# yadcf not searching the Value with render Colums

Tags: datatables, yadcf

am using yadcf with Datatable

javaScript:code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'data.asmx/getData',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#tableDiv").show();
                var t = $('#studentDataTable').DataTable({
                    data: data,                        
                    'columns': [
                     { 
                       data: null 
                       render: function (data, type, row)
                       {
                          return data['fname']+' '+data['mname']+' '+ data['lname'];
                       }  
                     },
                    ],
                });
                yadcf.init(t,
                [
                   {
                       column_number: 0,
                       filter_type: "auto_complete",
                   }
                   'footer',
                {
                    cumulative_filtering: true,
                }
            );
            t.draw();
            }
        });
    });
```

but When i type any data in the text box its not searching it.

I also tried Select filtering type that also not working,select box stays empty apart from default label.
anyone knows whats the Problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the [0.9.0.beta.12](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/77b1c8cae2b18c3451ea6811a6f03453ad24d83d/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) and use `column_data_type: rendered_html` for the filter, [see docs](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L73)

```
{
    column_number: 0,
    column_data_type: rendered_html,
    filter_type: "auto_complete",
}
```

As to your range slider - the following setup should be used (notice the ignore_char / filter_plugin_options

```
{
    column_number: 2,
    filter_type: "range_number_slider",
    ignore_char: "%",
    filter_plugin_options: {step:0.01}
}
```

see [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m52cqoom/9/)

If that won't help, provide a jsbin sample with your issue

Comment: while in browser console its says `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Ms. Rithu Rabin Dhanki`

Comment: ohh... thank You so much Sir you made my Day.
what was the problem in the auto complete sir ?

Comment: Sir one more question can we make the slider by default in 0 to 100 range ? and according to that the data will filter.

Comment: no issue in auto complete, just a fixed issue in yadcf regarding rendered_html, as to the 0...100 just use `data: [0, 100],`

Comment: sir i think a minor issue is their when we use `scrollX: true,` the number on the slider is not variating. [jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/m52cqoom/10/)

Comment: sir any update about this ? is their any alternate way for `scrollx: true`

Comment: please open an issue on https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues provide the jsfiddle and explain the issue and I will fix it when I'll have the time

Comment: done sir. and for now i manged my work by putting it outside the table.

Comment: Wait a min this problem only occur when i put the filters on `footer` on header its working fine 
[working fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/7zzdy8go/). and  updated the [issue](https://jsfiddle.net/7zzdy8go/)